# Payment System for Restful Spring API

Tags: java, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I am developing a RESTful API which will also handle client's payment by VISA, Master card and other available options. This is my first project where I will implement this service. That's why I am looking for some valuable advice, suggestions to make the **Payment System** *secure*, *reliable*, and most *effective* with modern technology.

Before writing my question I have done a short research where I have learnt about [Strip Payment](https://stripe.com/).

Any opinion regarding creating a online payment system is mostly welcome.

Comment: I'm also starting my first project on payment system. I'm also looking for suggestion from senior guys.

Comment: Way too broad to be a good fit for SO I'm afraid. FWIW, Stripe is likely a good option, specifically the connect API. Make sure you understand what you need to around PCI compliance, and bear in mind any ecommerce card payments in the EEA will soon need to implement SCA.

Comment: @VishalPatel, Probably I will go for Stripe. Let me know you found a better solution.

Comment: @MichaelBerry, Could you please say something about `payment gateway`. Should I learn about this or I can go for an API like Stripe?